# Need help creating a parallel array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

Just a disclaimer: I am a complete noob when it comes to C programming and this might be embarrassingly easy but I can't think it out myself and haven't found anything otherwise helpful. Anyways, this program below is supposed to put names (last, first) and ages into arrays and then alphabetize them. The problem I have is creating a sort of parallel array to match ages with their respective names after sorting them alphabetically. Does anyone have any suggestions? I was thinking of somehow tying the age array into my defined functions, but I still can't wrap my head around that either. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NAME_LENGTH 50
#define MAX_NAMES 50

int alpha_first(char *list[], int min_sub, int max_sub);
void select_sort_str(char *list[], int n);

int
main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int numpeople;
    char names[MAX_NAMES][NAME_LENGTH] = { 0 };
    char ages[MAX_NAMES][NAME_LENGTH] = { 0 };
    char skip_line;
    char *alpha[MAX_NAMES] = { 0 };

    printf("Enter number of people <0..50>\n> ");
    scanf("%d", &numpeople);

    do
    {
        scanf("%c", &skip_line);
    }
    while (skip_line != '\n');


    for(i = 0; i < numpeople; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter name %d (lastname, firstname) ", i+1);
        gets(names[i]);

        printf("Enter age %d: ", i+1);
        gets(ages[i]);

    }

    for(i = 0; i < numpeople; ++i)
    {
        alpha[i] = names[i];
        select_sort_str(alpha, numpeople);
    }

    printf("\n\n%-30s\n\n", "Original List");
    for  (i = 0;  i < numpeople;  ++i)
        printf("%-30s\n", names[i]);
    printf("\n\n%-30s\n\n", "Alphabetical Order");
    for  (i = 0;  i < numpeople;  ++i)
        printf("%-30s\n", alpha[i]);

    return 0;

}

int
alpha_first(char *list[],
            int min_sub, int max_sub)
{
    int first, i;

    first = min_sub;
    for (i = min_sub + 1; i <= max_sub; ++i)
            if (strcmp(list[i], list[first]) < 0)
                first = i;
    return (first);
}


void
select_sort_str(char *list[], int n)
{
    int fill, index_of_min;
    char *temp;

    for (fill=0; fill<n-1; ++fill)
    {
        index_of_min = alpha_first(list, fill, n - 1);

        if (index_of_min != fill)
        {
            temp = list[index_of_min];
            list[index_of_min] = list[fill];
            list[fill] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to create parallel arrays or can you get by with an array of `struct`s?

Answer (score 3):

Use a structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    char *first_name;
    char *last_name;
    int age;
} person;
```

When you create your array, create an array of `person`;  Create a new `person`, fill in its fields, add it to your array.  Now you have all of the data you need in one nice little package.

Answer (score 0):

Most problems in computer science are solved by introducing an extra level of indirection.

In this case, observe that `select_sort_str()` is sorting an array of pointers to strings.  Suppose instead you construct an array of index values, initialised to `0`..`numpeople-1`, and then you sort those indexes into the order of the corresponding names.  So, in `alpha_first()`, as well as taking `char* list[]` let it also take `int index[]` and the comparison becomes:

```
if (strcmp(list[index[i]], list[index[first]]) < 0)
```

and similarly `select_sort_str()`, in which you don't swap the entries in the `list[]` but in the `index[]`.  Then to read the entries in alpha order, you use the extra level of indirection:

```
names[index[i]]
```